# How to find min and max using for loop?

Tags: for-loop

Suppose that the names_scores is a dictionary that contains a pair of name and score for 8 students.
names_scores = { "Sara": 90, "Alex": 80, "James": 65, "Olivia": 76, "Lucca": 92, "Sen": 84, "Ali": 79, "Camilia": 97}

Use a for loop to find the maximum and the minimun scores
Dont use min() or max() functions
Use one for loop only to find both values (hint: use conditional statements)
Print the values of the min and the max scores

Answer (score 1):

You will have a hard time using a for loop for an object. If it has to be some kind of loop i would suggest a for...in or a for...of loop. Or you could use Object.key (returns all keys as an array) / Object.values (returns all values as an array)/ Object.entries(returns an nested array with key and values as items) and loop over with the .forEach method.

And to shorten things i am going to use an inline if.

So this

```
if(condition){
 doSomeThing();
}
```

is the same as

```
condition && doSomeThing();
```

With for...in loop:

```
let min: number = 0;
let max: number = 0;
for (const key in names_scores ) {
 const score: number = names_scores[key];
 min > number && min = number;
 max < number && max = number;
}
```

With for...of loop:

```
let min: number = 0;
let max: number = 0;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(names_scores)) {
 min > value && min = value;
 max < value && max = value;
}
```

With Object.keys

```
let min: number = 0;
let max: number = 0;

Object.keys(names_scores).forEach(key: string => {
 const value: number = names_scores[key];
 min > value && min = value;
 max < value && max = value;
})
```

With Object.values

```
let min: number = 0;
let max: number = 0;

Object.values(names_scores).forEach(value: number => {
 min > value && min = value;
 max < value && max = value;
})
```

With Object.entries

```
let min: number = 0;
let max: number = 0;

Object.keys(names_scores).forEach([key, value] => {
 min > value && min = value;
 max < value && max = value;
})
```

I would suggest you google those methods and try to understand it.
Have fun at school... or at wherever you copied this question from.